# Is it possible for an OP with less than 2k reputation points to approve, reject or improve edits?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, privileges

Looking at the review section on Cross Validated I realised that two OPs, each with reputation 1, reviewed Suggested Edit. How is that possible?

EDIT:

I'm attaching a picture taken today h. 10:21 a.m. (CET). In the red circled section I thought you can see participating only people with > 2k reputation points. But the [last](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/140470/user125535) OP in the queue (counting from left to right) has 106 reputation points. So, does this mean that he appears there because he did a Suggested Edit to its own post?

[image]

Comment: Were these suggested edits to their own posts?

Comment: Although this probably was not the case, sometimes users have their reputations reduced to 1 temporarily.  In other cases users give away many points in bounties, also lowering their reputations.  Therefore the reputation they have *now* might have no relationship with the reputation they had *at the time they took an action.*

Comment: @JNat good point. I have no idea how to get that information.

Comment: @whuber that's reasonable. But at the time I was writing the question for the first time, the OPs I was referring to were two new OPs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anyone can review, and approve or deny, edits to their own posts.  That is the case whether the post at issue is a question or an answer.  Moreover, their review is final:  That is, if they are the first reviewer, there is no need for a second, and if they are the second reviewer, but their review disagrees with the first, their choice is used.

---

When your reputation is >10k(?), you can see more of what's going on in the review queues.  It appears that was [user125535](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/140470/user125535).  They approved an edit to their own post.  Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Note that it is unlikely they went straight to the review queue and found this suggested edit.  They would have been notified through their inbox and followed a link to the suggested edit to approve or reject.

Comment: That's right, but let's add that it's not the only rule. For example, anyone with high enough reputation can edit a question or answer without needing the OP's approval. They in turn can roll back an edit, as sometimes happens. On occasion, I have had people reverse the whole of  a very detailed edit that focused on presentation alone. If that happens, I register a mild protest and back off. Usually the OP accepts such edits, and sometimes even thanks you.